# Set Font awesome and Input the same height HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make both font awesome symbol and input tag the same height?
Look like this:[image]

I want to use this HTML:

```
<p>
  <span class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></span>
  <span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
  </span>
</p>
```

And my CSS code:

```
input, span.fa {
  height: 46px;
}

span.fa {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLs1je66/
Thank you!

Comment: You can make the icon bigger if you add fa-2x for example <span class="fa fa-user fa-fw fa-2x"></span>

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this

```
input, span.fa {
    height: 46px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1px 13px;
}

input{
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

span.fa {
    background-color: #e4e3e3;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    color: #555;
}
```

[Click here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q5fenmat/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<i>` tag here:

```
<p>
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) property and `vertical-aling: top` to align them correctly:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
input,
span.fa {
  height: 46px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
span.fa {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
  <span class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
</p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLs1je66/1/)

---

**Update** - adding styles to the elements and some markup change, to look like in the image:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

p{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

input{
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
<span><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span><input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
</p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLs1je66/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I've create a fiddle , have a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/gA4rx/1191/

```css
.wrapper input[type="text"] {
    position: relative; 
}

input { 
font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    padding-left: 35px;
    line-height: 32px;
} /* This is for the placeholder */

.wrapper:before {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 32px;
    content: "\f007";
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p class="wrapper"><input placeholder="Full Name"/></p>
```